# Multiselect widget in Databricks notebook

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

I made multiselect widgets in the databricks notebook.

```py
dbutils.widgets.multiselect("Scenario", "Actual", [str(x) for x in scenario_type])
```

But I wanted to use the selected value to update the table I have.

Once there is only one item selected, it works.

```py
display(ur.filter((ur.scenario == getArgument("Scenario")))
```

However, if I select multiple items, it didn't obviously.

Do you know how to make multi-selection work in my scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the list from selected values and use `isin` method to filter the records.

```
myList = getArgument("Scenario").split(",")
display(ur.filter(ur.scenario.isin(myList)))
```